# populate primefaces datatable from a nativeQuery

Tags: datatable, primefaces, native, populate

im learning jsf enviroment, sry if this is kind of easy case for you ,

Im trying to populate a primefaces datatable from a native query , this is what i got at the moment

```
       //My native query is defined in my entity
       @NamedNativeQueries({@NamedNativeQuery(name="Tallt089.bandejaCitas",
       query ="select bandeja.ep_id_tallt089 idBandeja ...)})
       ...
       ...
```

I call this nativeQuery this way

```
        public List**<TablaBandejaCitas>** bandejaCitas(String cia, String agencia, String division) {
        Query query = em.createNamedQuery("Tallt089.bandejaCitas");
        query.setParameter(1,cia);
        query.setParameter(2,agencia);
        query.setParameter(3,division);
        return query.getResultList();
     //this works fine retrieves correctly my query
}
```

And use it on my managedBean

```
        public List**<TablaBandejaCitas>** bandejaCitas(String compania,
        String agencia,String division){
         return agendamientoSession.bandejaCitas(compania,agencia,division);  
        }
```

then referenced this on my jsf page like this

```
     <p:dataTable id="bandeja_citas" 
     value="#{AgendamientoMBean.bandejaCitas(UsuarioMBean.compania,UsuarioMBean.agencia,
     UsuarioMBean.divisionPK.diDivision)}"  
                             var="bandeja" 
                             paginator="true" rows="15"  >
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Bandeja Citas por confirmar/Llamadas por realizar
                    </f:facet>
                    <p:column headerText="Id Bandeja" >
                        <h:outputText value ="#{bandeja.idBandeja}"/>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="Cliente" sortBy="#{bandeja.cliente}" 
                        filterBy="#{bandeja.cliente}">
                       <h:outputText value ="#{bandeja.cliente}"/>
                    </p:column>
                ...
                ...
                ...
                 </p:dataTable>
```

I realized that the var property needs something like mapped of the fields of the query because the warnings on the jsf page tell me that this is an unkwon property

```
     <h:outputText value ="#{bandeja.**cliente**}"/>
```

I dont know how to store the query in that variable so the data can be displayed

right now i got a for input string exception like the component its reading raw data instead of formmatted list with the correct variable filled with the query fields ..

hope you can understandme

apreciatte your comments in advance :D

Comment: Is your bandejaCitas method just returning a default list of Object objects? You might need some casting to make sure its known you have Bandeja entity objects.  return (List<Bandeja>) query.getResultList();

Comment: Hi @Rich thanks for your answer . Yes its just returning a list Objects objects, can you show me an example on how to implement this <Bandeja> cast ? so i can correctly call it in the jsf page , I updated my code adding a cast but still not working

Comment: Sure, it was something I just noticed compared to code I've seen using the getResultList() which just returns Objects, so at least one step is letting Java known those Objects are actually a class you have with properties for each projection of the query. If the native query is not returning projections that are table columns mapped to properties in the Entity/Bandeja class then I think that's a problem.

Taking a step back, it might be helpful to answer your question if you can explain why you used a NativeQuery and generally what you are trying to pull from DB (a row or a multitable query?)

Comment: Ty @Rich really apreciatte your help . Yes its a multitable query , and the query doesnt represent a table of the db :S

Comment: Glad to help. So my next question is what is the persistence framework you are using? javax.persistence.Query is an interface so do you know what specific class your Query object is? The one you get from the EntityManager em. I'm wondering if there is a method available to iterate through the result set and you can feed the columns of each result into a custom Object that has a property for each column. Then the Primefaces datatable would not have issues accessing the properties of a list of known Object types.

Comment: Hi again :), im using eclipse toplink as persistence provider, i think the real problem is in the nativeQuery resultClass right now im not using anything there ,because maybe there is the feed of the columns so the primefaces datable can read , i was searching and there is a @SqlResultSetMapping and im trying to use it with my query have you used that annotation? you think that be the real problem? thanks in advance

Comment: @Rich its eclipse link persistence i confuse with toplink , and trying to use hibernate instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I solved this little problem. I did it by creating an entity class (even is not a table in the DB) with the columns that I select in the nativeQuery and then using this class as the resultClass option in the native:

```
resultClass=com.talleresZeusWeb.entidades.BandejaCitas.class
```

I was trying to make that sqlresultsetmapping annotation but don't know to use it in this case.

Hope someone finds this useful at some point, thank you for your responses @Rich